# Python and pytube getting a 'streamingData' error when trying to run

Tags: python, pytube

I'm been fighting with this for a while. I wrote a small front end for a YouTube downloader using pytube. For some reason, I get a 'streamingData' error every time I try to download a video. I tried several different ways of getting streams, but can't get it to work. I put in a few print statements and basically, the YouTube link is correct, but then it doesn't get to the *if* statement on line 14 and bombs out at the `video = yt_object.streams.get_highest_resolution()` on line 13 throwing the exception error of 'streamingData'. I'm running the latest version of `pytube` `(12.1.3)`. My source code is:

```
    import os
    import tkinter
    import customtkinter
    from pytube import YouTube
    
    
    def start_download():
        try:
            yt_link = link.get()
            print(yt_link)
            yt_object = YouTube(yt_link, on_progress_callback=on_progress)
            print(1)
            video = yt_object.streams.get_highest_resolution()
            if video:
                print(2)
                title.configure(text=yt_object.title, text_color="white")
                print(3)
                finish_label.configure(text="")
                print(4)
                video.download(output_path=f"{os.environ['UserProfile']}/Downloads")
                print(5)
                finish_label.configure(text='Download complete.')
            else:
                print("No highest resolution stream available.")
        except Exception as e:
            finish_label.configure(text=f"An error occurred: {e}", text_color="red")
    
    
    def on_progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
        total_size = stream.filesize
        bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining
        percentage_of_completion = bytes_downloaded / total_size * 100
        per = str(int(percentage_of_completion))
        progress_percentage.configure(text=f"{per}%")
    
        # Update progress bar
        progress_bar.set(float(percentage_of_completion / 100))
    
    
    # System Settings
    customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("Dark")
    customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")
    
    # Create the app frame
    app = customtkinter.CTk()
    app.geometry("720x480")
    app.title("YouTube Downloader")
    
    # Adding UI elements
    title = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="Insert a YouTube link:")
    title.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    
    # Link input
    url_var = tkinter.StringVar()
    link = customtkinter.CTkEntry(app, width=350, height=40, textvariable=url_var)
    link.pack()
    
    # Finished downloading
    finish_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="")
    finish_label.pack()
    
    # Progress percentage
    progress_percentage = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="0%")
    progress_percentage.pack()
    
    progress_bar = customtkinter.CTkProgressBar(app, width=400)
    progress_bar.set(0)
    progress_bar.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    
    # Download button
    download = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, text="Download", command=start_download)
    download.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
    
    # Run app
    app.mainloop()
```

Any thoughts or suggestions would be welcome! I even asked ChatGPT for help to no avail.

In following ewokx's recommendations, it throws this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Robert\PycharmProjects\YouTubeDownloader\venv\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 553, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "C:\Users\Robert\PycharmProjects\YouTubeDownloader\main.py", line 12, in start_download
    video = yt_object.streams.get_highest_resolution()
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Robert\PycharmProjects\YouTubeDownloader\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Robert\PycharmProjects\YouTubeDownloader\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 176, in fmt_streams
    stream_manifest = extract.apply_descrambler(self.streaming_data)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Robert\PycharmProjects\YouTubeDownloader\venv\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 161, in streaming_data
    return self.vid_info['streamingData']
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'streamingData'
```

Comment: Please include the traceback error.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I'm not a professional programmer and I'm only on day 43 of a UDemy Python 100 Days of Code class.

Comment: When you get the error, you just copy that and paste it in your post.

Comment: It doesn't give an error. If I exit the app is says "Process finished with exit code 0" so the only information I have is the exception it get in the try/except which just says "steamingData"

Comment: Since you've caught the exception,  do not wrap the code in the try/except block and then post the traceback error.

Comment: It won't let me add everything here, so I added it to the original post.

Comment: From the traceback, it seems like there is something wrong with the video (either it doesn't exist or something messed up).  Ensure you have the latest updates for your packages.  Unfortunately, that's as much as I can tell you without pertinant info on what you're downloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Basically, YouTube (well, the channel uploaders) mark most videos as 18+ and that causes PyTube to crap the bed. So, you need to set up authorization for the app to allow it to work. To fix this issue, I needed to add/change the following line:

```
yt_object = YouTube(yt_link, on_progress_callback=on_progress, use_oauth=True, allow_oauth_cache=True)
```

Now, the problem is that it send the auth dialog to the console and I can't figure out how to capture the code and display it in the GUI so I can make it a stand alone program...but that's another battle.

Thanks to ewokx for trying to help!